# Custom icons for plugins in menu

Tags: impresspages

I have built my own plugin in Impresspages. In a custom widget it is possible to add a custom icon by adding a "icon.svg" image in the assets folder. Is it also possible to add a custom Font Awesome icon in the menu for a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

To add widget icon, add icon.svg to your widget's assets directory. I think png would also work.

To add FontAwesome icon to your plugin, catch ipAdminMenu filter and modify your plugin's menu item by using ->setMenuIcon('fa-xxx') method. But I agree that this is a bit annoying. I believe it would be cool if admin menu icon setting would be added to the plugin.json file. If you feel confident, you can prepare a pull request for this feature.